# Refining my JavaScript text scrambler

Tags: javascript

Here's what I've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/CRASNY/dms3tvjj/6/

```
function scramble(a){a=a.split("");for(var b=a.length-1;0<b;b--){var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*(b+1));d=a[b];a[b]=a[c];a[c]=d}return a.join("")}

function scrambleText(){
console.log(1);
var textArea = document.getElementById('TEXTAREA_ID');
var lines = textArea.value.split('\n');
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    lines[i] = scramble(lines[i]).toUpperCase().split('').join(' ');
}
textArea.value = lines.join('\n');
}

document.getElementById('BUTTON_ID').onclick = scrambleText;
```

You can see that this takes the input and scrambles it, changes the case to uppercase, and puts a space between each letter. However, this doesn't work so great for strings that are multiple words long.

For example, `This sentence is a test` currently gets scrambled to something like `S T E   S   A I S S E C I E T E T   H N   T N`.

**What I'd like to achieve:** each word of a string is scrambled separately and wrapped by the `~` key. I'd also like for the input to be shown in output, separated by a `|` following the scrambled text.
An example output of  `This sentence is a test` would be `~H T S I~ ~E C N T E S N E~ ~S I~ ~A~ ~T T S E~|This sentence is a test`. Can anyone guide me on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another function that separates the words and scrambles each, and then finally joins them using the tidle character:

```
function scramblePhrase(_phrase) {
    var words = _phrase.split(/\s+/);
    words = words.map(function(_word) {
        return scramble(_word);
    });
    return words.join('~').toUpperCase();
}
function scramble(a){a=a.split("");for(var b=a.length-1;0<b;b--){var c=Math.floor(Math.random()*(b+1));d=a[b];a[b]=a[c];a[c]=d}return a.join("")}
```

From your `scrambleText()` function, call `scramblePhrase()` instead of `scramble()`.

Here's a modified version of you fiddle with the above in place: https://jsfiddle.net/dms3tvjj/8/

Answer (score 0):

To keep the form of your original implementation, you will have to add an additional layer of iteration to handle the separation of words for your case.

```
function scrambleText(){
  var textArea = document.getElementById('TEXTAREA_ID');
  var lines = textArea.value.split('\n');

  for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){ 
    var originalLine = lines[j];
    var words = lines[j].split(' ');
    for(var i = 0;i < words.length;i++){
       words[i] = '~' + scramble(words[i]).toUpperCase().split('').join(' ') + '~';
    }
    lines[j] = words.join('\n') + '|' + originalLine;
  }

  textArea.value = lines.join('\n');
}
```

Take into consideration that while adding one further level into the iteration won't cause chaos, adding further levels or more grandiose data manipulation into the bin will soon lead to code hard to comprehend. Check out techfoobar's answer for a possible method of reorganizing the code for better readability.
See working example over here: https://jsfiddle.net/dms3tvjj/9/